# Angular Error error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: java, angular, spring, jhipster

I have been unable to find why I am getting this error on a Angular project.

Plan contains and array of Tasks. Each Task contains an entity called MetaTime. MetaTime has a field TaskStart.

**plan.usergen.model.ts**

```
import { Moment } from 'moment';
import {ITaskUsergen} from "app/shared/model/task.usergen.model";

export interface IPlan {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  startDate?: Moment;
  tasks?: ITaskUsergen[];
}

export class Plan implements IPlan {
  constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public name?: string,
    public startDate?: Moment,
    public tasks?: ITaskUsergen[],
  ) {}
}
```

**task.usergen.model.ts**

```
import {ITask, Task} from "app/shared/model/task.model";
import {MetaTime} from "app/shared/model/meta-time.model";

export interface ITaskUsergen extends ITask {
  metaTime?: MetaTime;
}

export class TaskUserGen extends Task implements ITaskUsergen {
  constructor(public metaTime?: MetaTime) {
    super();
  }
}
```

**meta-time.model.ts**

```
import { Moment } from 'moment';

export interface IMetaTime {
  id?: number;
  taskStart?: Moment;
  taskDuration?: number;
  taskInterval?: number;
  taskRepeat?: number;
}

export class MetaTime implements IMetaTime {
  constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public taskStart?: Moment,
    public taskDuration?: number,
    public taskInterval?: number,
    public taskRepeat?: number
  ) {}
}
```

[image]

The full error is:

```
ERROR in src/main/webapp/app/entities/plan-usergen/plan-detail.component.html:47:46 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
47   <td>{{ task.metaTime.taskStart }}</td>
                                            ~~~~~~~~
src/main/webapp/app/entities/plan-usergen/plan-detail.component.ts:7:16
7   templateUrl: './plan-detail.component.html',
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component PlanDetailComponent.
```

Comment: That's "strict null checks", to turn it off try adding this option under "compilerOptions" in your tsconfig.js file

"strictNullChecks": true

Comment: set it to true or false to turn off?

Comment: You should not disable this and just handle the nullable object properly. Thanks to this error you're helped to catch bugs ahead of time.

Answer (score 8):

It's probably because you're compiling AOT (Ahead of Time) and the `metaTime` is nullable (the questionmark after `metaTime?`).

The compiler gives the error because it's pretty strict I think (not quite an angular expert myself) but you should do a null-check to prevent the possible null situation.

You can at least fix it by using this, the question is whether this is the behavior YOU expect to happen:

```
<td>{{ task.metaTime?.taskStart }}</td>
```

In the end it's all about having code that behaves like you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've made the entire chain of variables leading up to `taskStart` optional, technically any of them could be undefined, which would make it impossible to access the `taskStart` variable. You should either access it in a null-safe way or re-think weather the variables need to be optional.

Comment: Thanks. Would you have an example of a null safe access? you mean in the component?

Comment: So one primitive solution would be to have a function that would accept the task and try to access the start time after checking whether the previous variable is not undefined. For example:

`getTaskStart(task) {
    if (task && task.metaTime) {
        return task.metaTime.taskStart;
    }
}`